# Showing Events on a Datepicker with Server-side data

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have been busy creating a solution to a client that has proven to be a bit more difficult than I thought it would be. I am using the jQuery Datepicker widget to display calendar events (monthly view) from server-side code. Every thing in the following code works EXCEPT the CSS. It is not changing anything and it seems I've tried everything in the world.

A Calendar is shown in month-view on page-load (MVC) and if a user has events the day should have a different background-color. Also, when the user changes month-to-month, the same logic happens (ajax call to server). Again, this all is working well. My directive to change the background color will not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.expr[":"].exactly = function (el, i, m) {
            var s = m[3];
            if (!s) return false;
            return eval("/^" + s + "$/i").test($(el).text());
        };

        var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
        var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth();

        function getTheData(year, month) {
            var theYear = year;
            var theMonth = month;
            //alert(theYear + ", " + theMonth);

            $.post("GetMeSomeData", { year: theYear, month: theMonth }, function(data) {
                //cycle through the dates and address the CSS appropriately
                var i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar td a:exactly(' + data[i]['d'] + ')')
                        .css({ backgroundColor: 'blue' });
                }
            });
        }

        $('#date').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            beforeShowDay: getTheData(currentYear, currentMonth),
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                Date.prototype.toString = function () { return isNaN(this) ? 'NaN' : [this.getDate(), this.getMonth(), this.getFullYear()].join('/'); };
                d = new Date(dateText);
                //alert(d.getDate() + ", " + d.getFullYear());
                getTheData(d.getFullYear(), d.getDate());
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                //alert(year + ", " + month);
                getTheData(year, month);

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: isn't it:  `.css({ background-color: 'blue' });` ?

Comment: @cruxi Nope, the .css() version that receives an object the property is CamelCased, you refer to the other normal version `.css('background-color','blue');`

Comment: Try forcing the style with `.css('background-color','blue !important');`

Comment: I tried the forcing with !important. No gold. I'm wondering if I'm not looping through the return data right?